# Django: Join two models

Tags: django, join

I have two models like this:

```
class Author(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Book(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, related_name='book', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want to query all authors who own at least 1 book (we can do it in sql easily). So i tried:

```
Author.book.all()
```

and got an error: ReverseManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'
How can i do this with Django ORM?
Please help me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my bad, I solved it:
Author.objects.all(book__isnull=False)